# Hashicorp vault secret in kv is cleartext?

Tags: hashicorp-vault, secret-manager

In Hashicorp vault, I wasn't sure if it's feasible to encrypt the value(helloworld) as shown below
[image]

Theoretically based on the ADP from hashicorp, it's able to encrypt it but I wasn't sure if practially anyone had tried it before as it requires license? Please seek advice.

https://medium.com/hashicorp-engineering/advanced-data-protection-with-hashicorp-vault-76c3bcf8f498

Comment: It is encrypted *in storage*. But you are able to read it back in order to use it. That's what the UI does, by calling they API like your application or vault cli will do.